# When a ASPX page is opened using window.showModalDialog, Then that page showing Page.Header object as nothing

Tags: asp.net

I have ErrorMsg.aspx page which pops up using window.showModalDialog(..) I want to add javascript and CSS in the header of this page using code behind.
For adding javascript and CSS in header I need Header object of ErrorMsg.aspx page. But when I am checking PAGE object of this page the Header object is showing me NOTHING.
I am able to get Header object for other pages.

Is it a problem with window.showModalDialog(...)?

Comment: Have you changed your <head> tag to <head runat="server">?

Answer (score 0):

No, the page doesn't work any different on the server when it's opened using `showModalDialog`. The server isn't even aware that the page will end up there.

You need the `runat="server"` attribute in the `head` tag to be able to access it from server code:

```
<head runat="server">
```